# Unable to access API data and JSON parse error in java

Tags: java, json, api

SOLVED and code amended.

I'm trying to retrieve data from rotten tomato API using java, it's for a simple chat bot. My URI works when I paste it into my browser. But my code isn't returning the same results and i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

The second problem is that my 'JsonReader' cannot be resolve to a type and I don't have the option of importing it. I've been using [this guide!](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html)

Code as follow:

```
    String url = http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?q=queryText&page_limit=10&page=1&apikey=[]


            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url); //The URI to be used. 
                con = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection(); //OPen a connection to the URI

                //int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                //System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
                //System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);


                scan = new Scanner(urlObj.openStream());

            String strResultSet = "";
                while (scan.hasNext()) {
                    strResultSet+= scan.nextLine();
                     }

                //System.out.println("StrJson"+strResultSet);
                JSONObject JSONResultSet = new JSONObject(strResultSet);
                JSONArray results = JSONResultSet.getJSONArray("movies");
                JSONObject firstResult = results.getJSONObject(0);
                movie.setTitle(firstResult.getString(KEY_TITLE));
                movie.setId(firstResult.getString(KEY_ID));

                con.disconnect();
                scan.close();
```

Comment: Of course, the above JSON is not complete, and will not parse.  Is that all you received, or just a sample?

Comment: What do you mean by "default response"? I hope you're replacing the brackets in your URL with your actual API key.

Comment: The above JSON is just a sample yes. The movies array contained a number of JSON objects. By default I mean what is shown [in the documentation](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/Home), and yes i've been removing the angular brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using a scanner object to iterate through the result set.

```
scan = new Scanner(urlObj.openStream());
String strResultSet = "";
while (scan.hasNext()) { 
    strResultSet+= scan.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this could compile. You seem to be trying to get an InputStream from your "url" String.

You should be calling getConnection() on the HttpURLConnection, as in `con.getInputStream()`

Also, you are printing, but not actually checking the responseCode. It may not always indicate success.

Here's a good example from http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2012/01/17/HttpURLConnection

`void get(URL url) {

// this does no network IO 
  HttpURLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
  InputStream in;
  int http_status;
  try {

```
// this opens a connection, then sends GET & headers 
in = conn.getInputStream(); 

// can't get status before getInputStream.  If you try, you'll
//  get a nasty exception.
http_status = conn.getResponseCode();

// better check it first
if (http_status / 100 != 2) {
  // redirects, server errors, lions and tigers and bears! Oh my!
}
```

} catch (IOException e) {
    // Something horrible happened, as in a network error, or you
    //  foolishly called getResponseCode() before HUC was ready.
    // Essentially no methods of on "conn" now work, so don't go
    //  looking for help there.
  }

try {
    // now you can try to consume the data
    try_reading(in);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // Network-IO lions and tigers and bears! Oh my!
  } finally {
    // Do like Mom said and practice good hygiene.
    conn.disconnect(); 
  }
}`